# Using Eclipse indigo custom button makes button dissapear

Tags: android

btw i am just learning so bear with me ive got all my code correct as far as i can tell my main.xml reads

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/LOGIN"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/LOGIN"
 android:textSize="25dp"
 android:background="@drawable/custombutton"/>
```

custombutton.xml

```
<item
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/musicnotes1"/>
<item
android:state_focused="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/musicnotes2"/>
```

created a custombutton.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class custombutton extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.drawable.custombutton);
    }
}
```

and I have the android manifest correct as well no errors showing why  is my button gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your content view to be `R.drawable.custombutton` when it should be `R.layout.main`

*For example:*

```
setContentView(R.drawable.custombutton);
```

*should be:*

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Also, you posted your main.xml source but be sure that your button is inside of a layout.

*For example:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LOGIN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/LOGIN"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And your background drawable selector should be wrap in a selector like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/musicnotes1" 
    />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/musicnotes2" 
    />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/default" 
    />
</selector>
```

Perhaps you are forgetting to have a default image?